Real time data not display it return an error message: {"error": "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'body'"}
I like to implement real time data display in django app using Ajax, i want to enable user to be able to see what they are writing in real time, to do this, i'm using django JsonResponse, using the below method:
def get_real_time_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = request.POST.get('body')

        try:
            question = Question.objects.filter(body=body)
            if question is not None:
                content = question.body
                response_data = {
                    'content': content
                }
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'No content found for the given body'}, status=404)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'}, status=400)

Using the above method, it's means, every time, a user started writing something in the form, the data will be displayed in real time, but I don't know why the data does not display, instead, it return an error message in the browser console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
question/:89 {"error": "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'body'"}
error @ question/:89
:8000/get-real-time-data/:1 
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
question/:89 {"error": "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'body'"}
error @ question/:89
jquery.min.js:2 
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-real-time-data/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

my template:
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            {{ form }}
                            <div id="id_value"></div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getCookie(name) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    const cookie = cookies[i].trim();

                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            function updateRealTimeData() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'get_real_time_data' %}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')},
                    data: {},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#id_value').text(data.content);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
            setInterval(updateRealTimeData, 5000);
        });
    </script>

my models:
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    body = models.TextField()


.filter(…) [Django-doc] does not return a single object or None, it returns a QuerySet of Questions, so a collection of items. You can use .first() [Django-doc] to get the first item of that collection or None, so:
def get_real_time_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = request.POST.get('body')

        try:
            question = Question.objects.filter(body__icontains=body).first()
            if question is not None:
                content = question.body
                response_data = {'content': content}
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
            else:
                return JsonResponse(
                    {'error': 'No content found for the given body'}, status=404
                )
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'}, status=400)
It is also possible that there are multiple Questions, so returning only the first item is a bit strange.

10 seconds to late for my answer.

The data isn't shown, instead, it return another error from browser console: `{"error": "Cannot use None as a query value"}

@Bubble: your data: {},, so request.POST.get('body') will be empty.

Maybe because we are using .first() , when i try to write something, it does display the first object in the Question model, and that is not what I'm looking for Willem.

@Bubble: then you should remove the .first() and enumerate over the queryset.

When I do remove the .first(), how can I enumerate over the queryset and displayed the object? After i remove the .first(), it's still returning an error: {"error": "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'body'"}

@Bubble: you will need to enumerate over the queryset, create a list of results, and pass that as JSON response.

Can you provide us with how we can do that? I want to mark the answer as a recommended answer.
